# Фильтрация данных по различным критериям, без применения цикла

Tags: r

Имеется такая часть данных

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(type = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), time = as.POSIXct(c("2017.01.25 11:18:30", "2017.01.26 09:43:59", "2017.01.31 13:40:30", "2017.02.06 08:00:00", "2017.02.07 22:58:30", "2017.02.17 11:02:30", "2017.02.24 19:11:40", "2017.03.07 11:59:30", "2017.03.08 11:26:20", "2017.03.09 10:46:20", "2017.01.23 13:22:40", "2017.01.25 11:18:30", "2017.01.26 09:43:59", "2017.01.31 13:40:30", "2017.02.03 15:30:40", "2017.02.06 11:08:30", "2017.02.07 22:58:30", "2017.02.08 15:12:05", "2017.02.08 16:23:30", "2017.02.10 16:54:40", "2017.01.25 11:18:30", "2017.01.26 11:18:10", "2017.01.31 16:29:15", "2017.02.06 08:00:00", "2017.02.07 22:58:30", "2017.02.17 11:26:30", "2017.02.24 20:33:40", "2017.03.07 16:10:05", "2017.03.08 11:26:20", "2017.03.09 10:51:20"), tz = "GMT", format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"), part = c(0.36, 0.34, 0.33, 0.39, 0.24, 0.34, 0.33, 0.56, 0.41, 0.48, 0.25, 0.35, 0.33, 0.32, 0.27, 0.39, 0.24, 0.21, 0.41, 0.26, 0.36, 0.34, 0.33, 0.39, 0.24, 0.33, 0.32, 0.56, 0.41, 0.48))
```

Необходимо выполнить последующие действия:
1. По выбранному диапазону даты (например 2 недели) сформировать таблицу с вычисленными данными. Объясню на примере:
Задан диапазон даты две недели с 2017-01-21 по 2017-02-04, выбираю все значения part в исходных данных с датой входящей в этот диапазон дат + с определенным значением "type".
2. Из получившегося сформировать таблицу с просуммированными значениями колонки "part", другая колонка будет некая f(part).
3. Выбрать вариант с наибольшим значением sum(part)
  Из данного примера это будет:
   type                  date sum_part   f_part
1:    1 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369
2:    2 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.52 3.289474
3:    3 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369
  Будет выбран вариант с type = 2, но по другой сортировке надо выбрать type = 1 и type = 3. Эти варианты уже нужно записывать в другие таблицы, чтобы дальше с ними работать.
4. Далее смещаемся на одну неделю, т. е. диапазон двухнедельный теперь с 2017-01-28 по 2017-02-11, и все тоже самое что и с тем диапазоном.
5. Также нужно ставить разные диапазоны недель, 3, 4, и т. д.

Такая многоуровневая фильтрация, с последующими вычислениями и подготовки данных
слишком долгая через циклы, т. к. исходных данных очень много. Я просто склеиваю результаты подготовленные через циклы и потом склеенные фильтрую по условиям. Уверен используя векторизацию, и функции семейства apply приведут к более быстрому и изящному решению, но мне не хватает знаний и практики. С датами я думал придти к решению через упорядоченные факторы диапазонов, но пока не получается. Может вы мне что-нибудь подскажете? Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Пример готовых результатов из приведенных данных выше:

```
   type                  date sum_part   f_part
1:    1 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369
2:    2 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.52 3.289474
3:    3 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369
```

В колонке "date" указан диапазон даты, в который входят значения "part", эти значения суммируем, в колонке "f_part" используем некую функцию к сумме этих значений, отбираем наибольшее значение по сумме, заносим в таблицу, это второе значение, по функции первое и третье.

```
# of sum  
   type                  date sum_part   f_part
      2 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.52 3.289474  

# of function
   type                  date sum_part   f_part
      1 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369
      3 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369
```

Далее смещаемся на одну неделю по дате, т. е. уже диапазон 2017-01-28 2017-02-11 и повторяем:

```
   type                  date sum_part   f_part
1:    1 2017-01-28 2017-02-11     0.96 5.208333
2:    2 2017-01-28 2017-02-11     2.10 2.380952
3:    3 2017-01-28 2017-02-11     0.96 5.208333
```

В уже созданную таблицу # of sum добавляем наибольшее значение из этой таблицы, и с # of function также

```
    # of sum  
       type                  date sum_part   f_part
          2 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.52 3.289474  
          2 2017-01-28 2017-02-11     2.10 2.380952

    # of function
       type                  date sum_part   f_part
          1 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369
          3 2017-01-21 2017-02-04     1.03 4.854369  
          3 2017-01-28 2017-02-11     0.96 5.208333
          1 2017-01-28 2017-02-11     0.96 5.208333
```

И так далее...

Comment: Что касается apply, [вот здесь](https://habr.com/company/infopulse/blog/274611/?mobile=no) хорошо разжевано, и понятные примеры.

Comment: Пример итогового результата был бы весьма полезен.

Comment: Может для моего случая лучше не apply, а функции с пакета dplyr или data.table

Comment: Добавил пример @ArtemKlevtsov

Answer (score 1):

Векторизация предполагает определенный образ мышления (сразу над группами элементов), в отличии от обычного процедурного подхода, когда перебирают каждый элемент.

В Вашем случае необходимо сгруппировать записи в рамках одного диапазона, но этой информации в данных как раз и нет.

Если дополнить исходные данные еще одним столбцом, который бы показывал к каком диапазону данная строка относится, то дальнейшие действия укладываются в стандартный набор манипуляций с данными:

1. сгруппировать;
2. проссумироват по критериям групп;
3. наложить фильтры.

Реализация работает, но вижу проблему в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ:СС (не выверял на данный предмет).
Еще проблем когда в одном диапазоне записи с одинаковым значением, но разными type. Например: 1 - 1.45, 3 - 1.45, но это уже дело техники, провести проверку на уникальность.

Использую пакет `dplyr`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

#формируем тестовый набор данных
dt <- data.table(type = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), time = as.POSIXct(c("2017.01.25 11:18:30", "2017.01.26 09:43:59", "2017.01.31 13:40:30", "2017.02.06 08:00:00", "2017.02.07 22:58:30", "2017.02.17 11:02:30", "2017.02.24 19:11:40", "2017.03.07 11:59:30", "2017.03.08 11:26:20", "2017.03.09 10:46:20", "2017.01.23 13:22:40", "2017.01.25 11:18:30", "2017.01.26 09:43:59", "2017.01.31 13:40:30", "2017.02.03 15:30:40", "2017.02.06 11:08:30", "2017.02.07 22:58:30", "2017.02.08 15:12:05", "2017.02.08 16:23:30", "2017.02.10 16:54:40", "2017.01.25 11:18:30", "2017.01.26 11:18:10", "2017.01.31 16:29:15", "2017.02.06 08:00:00", "2017.02.07 22:58:30", "2017.02.17 11:26:30", "2017.02.24 20:33:40", "2017.03.07 16:10:05", "2017.03.08 11:26:20", "2017.03.09 10:51:20"), tz = "GMT", format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"), part = c(0.36, 0.34, 0.33, 0.39, 0.24, 0.34, 0.33, 0.56, 0.41, 0.48, 0.25, 0.35, 0.33, 0.32, 0.27, 0.39, 0.24, 0.21, 0.41, 0.26, 0.36, 0.34, 0.33, 0.39, 0.24, 0.33, 0.32, 0.56, 0.41, 0.48))

#формируем дату начала и конца периода для анализа

dt.b <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2017-01-21 00:00:01", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) # дата для начала диапазона
dt.e <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2017-04-30 23:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) # дата для начала диапазона

#задаем количество дней в диапазоне
ds <- 14 

#формируем список дат, по которым будем проводит анализ
dt.ds <- data.frame("dt.tst" = seq(dt.b, dt.e, 24*60*60))

#проставляем периоды на датах
##создаем столбец где проставляем номер строки для записи
dt.ds <- dt.ds %>% mutate(row = as.numeric(rownames(dt.ds))) 

##вычисляем номер диапазона на основе количества дней в диапазоне и количества номера строки
##значения номера строки / на количество дней в диапазоне, потом берем только целое значение 
##это и будет номером диапазона
dt.ds <- dt.ds %>% mutate(prd = floor((row-1)/ds)+1)

#подготовительные мероприятия
#определяем номер диапазона для даты из dt$time сопоставив дату из нашего сгенерированного 
#списка, объединяя по значению даты
##дополняем dt полем содержащим только значение даты
dt <- dt %>% mutate(only.dt = substr(as.character(time), 1, 10))

##аналогично для нашего сгенерированого списка с диапазонами
dt.ds <- dt.ds %>% mutate(only.dt = substr(as.character(dt.tst), 1, 10))

##проводим объединение
dt.wrk <- dt %>% left_join(dt.ds, by = "only.dt")

#удаляем столбцы не относящиеся к делу
dt.wrk <- dt.wrk %>% select(-row)

#основные действия для решения поставленной задачи
#получаем значения сумм для каждого периода и типа 
dt.wrk1 <- dt.wrk %>% group_by(prd, type) %>% summarise(spart = sum(part))

#находим максимальные значения в периоде и типе (накладываем фильтр)
#т.к. по полю периода и типа уже сгруппированно, то в результате получим в каждом периоде,
#для каждого типа максимальное значение
dt.wrk2 <- dt.wrk1 %>% filter(spart == max(spart))

#аналогично, но уже предыдущем, но только уже не 
dt.wrk3 <- dt.wrk1 %>% filter(spart != max(spart))

#для результирующи таблиц dt.wrk2 (максимальные значения), dt.wrk3 (все кроме макимальных значений)
#надо перейти от номеров периодов к датам
##группируем по периоду и в рамках одного диапазона находим минимальное значение (это будет начало диапазона)
##максимальное значение (это бдует конец периода)
dt.ds1 <- dt.ds %>% group_by(prd) %>% mutate(dt.bb = min(dt.tst), dt.ee = max(dt.tst))
dt.ds2 <- dt.ds1 %>% group_by(prd, dt.bb, dt.ee) %>% summarise(nr = n())

#с помощью объединения получаем привычные вид с датами начала и конца диапазонов
dt.rmax <- dt.wrk2 %>% left_join(dt.ds2, by = "prd")
dt.rnomax <- dt.wrk3 %>% left_join(dt.ds2, by = "prd")
```

Результат:

```
> print(dt.rmax)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   prd [?]
    prd type  spart dt.bb               dt.ee                  nr
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
1     1 2      1.52 2017-01-21 00:00:01 2017-02-03 00:00:01    14
2     2 2      1.51 2017-02-04 00:00:01 2017-02-17 00:00:01    14
3     3 1      0.33 2017-02-18 00:00:01 2017-03-03 00:00:01    14
4     4 1      1.45 2017-03-04 00:00:01 2017-03-17 00:00:01    14
5     4 3      1.45 2017-03-04 00:00:01 2017-03-17 00:00:01    14


> print(dt.rnomax)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   prd [?]
    prd type  spart dt.bb               dt.ee                  nr
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
1     1 1      1.03 2017-01-21 00:00:01 2017-02-03 00:00:01    14
2     1 3      1.03 2017-01-21 00:00:01 2017-02-03 00:00:01    14
3     2 1      0.97 2017-02-04 00:00:01 2017-02-17 00:00:01    14
4     2 3      0.96 2017-02-04 00:00:01 2017-02-17 00:00:01    14
5     3 3      0.32 2017-02-18 00:00:01 2017-03-03 00:00:01    14
```

Делаю промежуточные таблицы для удобства просмотра промежуточных результатов, но количество временных таблиц  можно и сократить